# How can I show only one div id from an external html file inside a popup modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some content on an external html file that I am displaying in a popup modal using [jQuery Modal](https://jquerymodal.com/). I am able to display the whole page fine, but I would like to only show one div at a time depending on which link is clicked.

The content on the external page looks like this:

```
<div class="review" id="one">This is review #1</div>
<div class="review" id="two">This is review #2</div>
<div class="review" id="three">This is review #3</div>
```

The links on the main page are coded like:

```
<a class="link" href="external.html" data-target="#two" rel="modal:open">Read review</a>
```

Then I have some Javascript that I thought would allow it to only show the selected div id depending on which link is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');

    $('.review').not(target).hide();
    $(target).show();
  });
});
```

This shows all the content from the external html and not just one selected div.

Is there a way to show only one div id from an external html loaded into a modal?

**Update:**
I have attempted to implement Bhojendra's solution below, but am now getting the error:

```
"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.$blocker.fadeOut')"
```

The link to view the code:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n61Buty8oexE369jdxCi4lZ9M9wj2SaP

Comment: The #modal-content dom element doesnt exist as @Bhojendra Rauniyar noted.

Comment: @Webbanditten I updated the code and removed the extra script as well as added the div "modal-content" before the closing body. And now I am getting another error: "null is not an object ". Updated code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n61Buty8oexE369jdxCi4lZ9M9wj2SaP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [example](https://jquerymodal.com/#example-4) that you linked, you can do like:

```
$('.link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).data('target');
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).find(target).appendTo('body').modal();
  });
});
```

A better to have modal content wrapper in your body:

```
<div id="modal-content"></div>
```

Now, in jQuery, use this:

```
$('#modal-content').html($(content).find(target)).modal()
// html parameter renamed ^^ to content
```

I meant to use:

```
$('.link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).data('target');
  $.get(this.href, function(content) {
    $('#modal-content').html($(content).find(target)).modal()
  });
});
```

Comment: When I add in the first bit of JS above, the modal loads the page, but all divs are now set to display:none; How come it's not displaying any of the divs now?

What did you mean by "better to have modal content wrapper in your body?"

Comment: What is the "html parameter" supposed to be?

Comment: `function(html) {`

Comment: When I add in the modal content wrapper into body and add the line of jQuery, I get the error "Can't find variable: target"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reason. Maybe I have something out of order. Can you please take a look here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n61Buty8oexE369jdxCi4lZ9M9wj2SaP

Comment: Now I'm seeing: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: content"

Comment: You have extra script. Remove `
<script>
$('#modal-content').html($(content).find(target)).modal()
// html parameter renamed ^^ to content
</script>`

Comment: And add `<div id="modal-content"></div>` before closing body.

Comment: I updated the code and removed the extra script as well as added the div "modal-content" before the closing body. And now I am getting another error: "null is not an object ". Updated code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n61Buty8oexE369jdxCi4lZ9M9wj2SaP

Comment: What is null being referred? Line number...?

Comment: The error is now coming from jquery.modal.min.js - line 60.

`!t && this.options.doFade ? this.$blocker.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration, this.unblock.bind(this, !0)) : (this.$blocker.children().appendTo(this.$body), this.$blocker.remove(), this.$blocker = null, n(), o.modal.isActive() || this.$body.css("overflow", ""))`